# Updating symfony2 forms : selecting which fields to show

Tags: forms, symfony

I'd like to allow a candidate that previously register to come back to his registration and add (and only) missing documents.

Here is my view

```
<form action="{{ path('candidat_update', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}>

    {% if ((entity.file2)==0)%}                       
        {{ form_row(edit_form.file2, { 'label': 'file2' }) }}
    {% endif %}

    <p>
        <button class="btn-small" type="submit">update</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

When clicking on button update, nothing is happening (no redirection to show view, no upload)

My controller's updateAction :

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('EtienneInscriptionBundle:Candidat')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Candidat entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);   
    $editForm = $this->createForm(new CandidatType(), $entity);  

    $editForm->bind($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('candidat_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        #return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('candidat_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

Where CandidateType contains the builder that generates initially every fields on create action (CRUD based controller)

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{        

    $builder     
        ->add('name') ....etc...
```

Any ideas on what's wrong ?
Thanx

Comment: They key here is in the `buildForm` class, which you haven't given all the details of. You decide in there which fields of the entity you're allowing to edit

Comment: You may want to change the buildForm method in such a way it only constructs the form with the relevant fields.

Comment: thanx , the problem is that i have 4 fields ( documents to upload or not), it means i have 16 possible combinations...how can i dela with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to filter your form fields in your template. 
Better is to use options when building your form. Here's an example on how you can do it,

1) Set conditions to add fields to your form,

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('field_a', 'type');
    // ...
    if ($options['allow_edit_field_b']) {
        $builder->add('field_b', 'text', array(
            'property_path' => false,
        ));
    }
    // ...
```

2) Define your options,

```
 public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'allow_edit_field_b' => false,
        ));
 }
```

3) Build your Form,

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new YourType(), $yourObject, array(
        'allow_edit_field_b' => true,
    ));
```

Comment: "It's not a good idea to filter your form fields in your template."

Why?

Comment: Put another way, why building fields to hide them in your template, isn't it better to adapt your form according to what you want the user to edit?

Comment: thanx ahmed , that is useful....but.... since i have 4 fields ( the documents to upload), it means i have 16 possible combinations ...

Comment: how would u deal with that? the selection on view seem to be a solution if i manage to pass the   if ($editForm->isValid())

Comment: i would need to put somewhere somewhat : if ( $entity->getFile1_bool() ) allow_edit_file1' => true; if ( $entity->getFile2_bool() ) allow_edit_file2' => true; etc .... before or while calling the createForm method ?

Comment: I think it's ok to add options if you have only 4 fields. You'll then have 4 conditions when building your form. In your view, if you want to render your fields individually, you've to check if each field is defined before rendering it.

Comment: You need to define the option when creating your form (check the third step in my answer), you'll then have something like,
 $form = $this->createForm(new YourType(), $yourObject, array(
        'allow_edit_field_b' => ($entity->getFieldBValue()) ? true : false,
         'allow ....' => .... ,
    ));